# Putting a GestureOverlayView in a ScrollView so that gestures can still be recorded - Android

Tags: java, android, scrollview, gesture

I'm trying to put a GestureOverlayView inside a scrollview so that I can scroll down and a GestureOverlayView will be there. However, the GestureOverlayView isn't recording my gestures. When I try to gesture on it, the entire window just scrolls.

Is there a way to disable the scrolling when I am touching the GestureOverlayView and still have it record my gestures?

Here's my xml roughly. I have a scrollview that houses a webview and a gestureoverlayview. I want to be able to scroll through the webview and have the gestureoverlayview be at the bottom of the webview. Then I want to be able to make a gesture. Right now, the gestureoverlayview is underneath the webview just fine. But I can't make a gesture, because the screen just scrolls rather than recognizing my gestures.

```
     <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" >

            <GestureOverlayView
                android:id="@+id/gesture"
                android:layout_width="650dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
                android:fadeEnabled="false"
                android:fadeOffset="5"
                android:gestureColor="@color/black"
                android:gestureStrokeAngleThreshold="0.1"
                android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="0.1"
                android:gestureStrokeSquarenessThreshold="0.1"
                android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
                android:gestureStrokeWidth="1.2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical" >
            </GestureOverlayView>
          </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you show us code?

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Anyone has resolved this issue?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You'd have to make your own gesture capture area in html and JavaScript and put it in the webview